# angular http post content-type application/json not working

Tags: json, angular, applicationcontext

the problem is i need to send json, but the content-type is text/plain, when i change it to application/json, there throw me a error (case 2)

but its working correctly with postman, sended with POST, the json in body raw(JSON)

i'm using angular HttpClient for send data with POST to my webservice .net
my webservice only accept json as message format
[.net web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMHow.png)

in my angular the http post service is used with observable like this
[angular http post sendData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lan6D.png)

in the case 1, i don't use any headers, only send the json with POST, but is sending with text/plain and the result is have 400 bad request
[packet sender log case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYHzB.png)

in the case 2, when i use headers (content-type, application/json), the method POST automatically change to OPTIONS, in packet sender looks like don't have any headers
[packet sender log case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv2WN.png)

in case 3, i tried with another header, content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the result was the content-type changed but my webservice not accept this
[packet sender log case 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP1SC.png)

any idea how to set('Content-Type', 'application/json') in the headers and works with POST?

thanks

Comment: Don’t stringify your payload and remove all headers you have set..

Comment: hello, if i dont use any headers like case 1 but send the list without json.stringfy, the result is case 2 photo

Comment: Yeah, that is a CORS issue. The OPTIONS response doesn’t have the correct headers.

Comment: do you have any guide or video for this issue? i don't find anything for angular preflighted requests

Comment: Its not Angular that does the preflight, the browser does that. Loads of SO issues to be found on Cors..